# How to disable a virtual product, simple product using sql query in magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2.2, sql

I'm using Magento2.2. The website which I had developed is frequently update stock, price from ERP. I need to disable only a product whether it is virtual or simple when stock is 0. And enable it again when stock is 1 using SQL.

Comment: have set any cron jobs for this or called any API from ERP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As magento product folow  the EAV structure that**

You need to write a *Query* between `eav_attribute` and `catalog_product_entity_int` table

Magento save product  status on table `catalog_product_entity_int` table. Save it as 1 and 2.

- **1 for enable**
- **2 for disable.**

### SQL query:

```
update catalog_product_entity_int set value= 2 WHERE 
attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
    WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
)  
And entity_id in 
(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` where type_id in('simple','grouped'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do it via SQL it will break as soon as the database layout changes.
Do it properly via API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html

Answer (score 0):

update catalog_product_entity_int set value= 2 WHERE
attribute_id = (
SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status' AND entity_type_id = 4
)
And row_id in
(SELECT row_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` where sku in('skus'))